# How to fix Max occupancy was not provided by transaction processor

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I have problem creating the Hyperledger Sawtooth network on `Ubuntu 18.04`. I see following warning message when I Start the Transaction Processor on the validator node.

```
[2019-10-14 13:53:59.875 WARNING  processor_handlers] Max occupancy was not provided by transaction processor: d999e8764d878b733de3b8068e3cc309dcd4ef4ca48ddb4b6e41196b329f7e2f7489527f6996ca20bb389949bb6ae31ad5809e52c911fed6ae7cacdc4ced0588. Using default max occupancy: 10
```

What could be an issue in my setup?

Answer (score 0):

This trace is nothing to be worried about, at least not the smart contract developers. Probably, warning is not the log level for this trace message.

Max occupancy is the number of transactions that a Transaction Processor can handle simultaneously. By default it is set to 10. If more than 10 transactions are available then the Validator will wait until an occupancy is available for the next transaction execution. This is introduced so that the Transaction Processor is not overwhelmed with the requests in the name of parallelism. The Transaction Processor can set this value during registration request.

Note: When I say transaction execution simultaneously, the Validator would consider them for execution only when all the dependencies are resolved.